# Does the variance of regression coefficient in multiple linear regression increases if we replace one of the predictors with its immediate parent?

Tags: multiple-regression, causality, treatment-effect

We have a data generation process as follows:

\begin{align}
Z_1 &= E_{Z_1}\\
Z_2 &= \theta_{Z_2} + \theta_{Z_1 Z_2} Z_1 + E_{Z_2} \label{Z2BasedOnZ1}\\
T   &= \theta_{T} + \theta_{Z_1 T}   Z_1 + E_{T} \\
M_1 &= \theta_{M_1} + { \theta_{{T}{M_1}} } T     + E_{M_1} \\
M_2 &= \theta_{M_2} + { \theta_{{M_1}{M_2}} }M_1 + E_{M_2} \\
Y   &= \theta_{Y} + { \theta_{{M_2}{Y}} } M_2 + \theta_{{Z_2}{Y}}Z_2 + E_Y
\end{align}

We assume that $E_{Z_1}$, $E_{Z_2}$, $E_{T}$, $E_{M_1}$, $E_{M_2}$, and $E_Y$ are independent from each other, and come from $N(0,\sigma^2)$. We are interested in estimating the average causal effect (ACE) of $T$ on $Y$, and estimating the variance of ACE.

**Case 1: All the variables are observed:**
The estimate of ACE and its variance is defined as:

\begin{align}
\widehat{ACE}(t) &= \hat{E}[Y|do(t+1)] - \hat{E}[Y|do(t)] = \hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_2}{Y}}\\
{var}(\widehat{ACE}(t)) &= {var}(\hat{E}[Y|do(t+1)] - \hat{E}[Y|do(t)]) = var(\hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_2}{Y}})
\end{align}

**Case 2: $Z_2$ is latent:** In this case, in the last equation, instead of regressing $M_2$ and $Z_2$ on $Y$, we should regress $M_2$ and $Z_1$ on $Y$. Hence our equations become:

\begin{align}
Z_1 &= E_{Z_1}\\
T   &= \theta_{T} + \theta_{Z_1 T}   Z_1 + E_{T} \\
M_1 &= \theta_{M_1} + { \theta_{{T}{M_1}} } T     + E_{M_1} \\
M_2 &= \theta_{M_2} + { \theta_{{M_1}{M_2}} }M_1 + E_{M_2} \\
Y   &= \theta'_{Y} + { \theta'_{{M_2}{Y}} } M_2 + \theta'_{{Z_1}{Y}}Z_1 + E'_Y
\end{align}

The estimate of ACE and its variance are:

\begin{align}
\widehat{ACE}(t) &= \hat{E}[Y|do(t+1)] - \hat{E}[Y|do(t)] = \hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}'_{{M_2}{Y}}\\
{var}(\widehat{ACE}(t)) &= {var}(\hat{E}[Y|do(t+1)] - \hat{E}[Y|do(t)]) = var(\hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}'_{{M_2}{Y}})
\end{align}

How can we compare $var(\hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}'_{{M_2}{Y}})$ with $var(\hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_2}{Y}})$? I expect that $var(\hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}'_{{M_2}{Y}})$ > $var(\hat{\theta}_{{T}{M_1}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_1}{M_2}} \hat{\theta}_{{M_2}{Y}})$, because $Z_2$ is the immediate parent of $Y$ and by replacing it with $Z_1$, we are reducing certainty about $Y$, and hence increasing the variance. Any thoughts?